# File write operation return value does not match value returned by tell()

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following code, `f.write(...)` returns `60` but immediately succeeding `f.tell()` returns `63`.
I am unable to understand why there is this difference of `3`. Could someone please explain. Using Python 3.5 on windows.

```
>>> f = open('c:\\tmp\\tut.txt', 'w')
>>>
>>> f.write(''' My name is Bot
... I am writing a file
...         To read it back
... ''')
60
>>> f.tell()
63
```

Comment: ...can not reproduce (on linux: python 3.6).

Comment: It's probably because Windows expands newline characters into a pair of characters (carriage return plus newline).  So each newline character in Python becomes two characters in your Windows text file.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist It's a Windows file problems.  It won't occur under Unix.

Comment: @TomKarzes i think you are right. but why does `write` mess that up? the doc says it returns the number of bytes written.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I suspect it's a logical-vs.-physical issue.  Logically, Python considers newline characters to be single characters.  When they're actually written to the file, they are converted to pairs of characters.  If you read it back in, it might convert them back to single characters (I'm not certain about that).  But if you just look at the raw file statistics, it gives the physical byte count.

Comment: @hard_working_ant I was the one who posted the explanation, not hiro.

Comment: Thanks @TomKarzes - sorry mixed it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try to add `b` to your opening file statement:

```
>>> f = open('c:\\tmp\\tut.txt', 'wb')  # change 'w' -> 'wb'
```

and make sure your problem goes away. Because by default you're opening the file in the text mode, and LF is getting expanded to CRLF.

Comment: You should not use `b` for text files under Windows.  The byte counts might match, but you'll end up with a text file that Windows doesn't understand.  Wrong approach.

Comment: Well thanks @lenik - this works fine and reads fine as well.

>>> f = open('c:\\tmp\\tut.txt', 'wb')
>>>
>>>
>>> str = ''' My name is Bot
... I am writing a file
...         To read it back
... '''
>>>
>>> f.write(bytes(str, 'utf-8'))
60
>>>
>>> f.tell()
60
>>>
>>> f = open('c:\\tmp\\tut.txt')
>>>
>>> #b = f.read()
... print(bytes(f.read(), encoding= 'utf-8'))
b' My name is Bot\nI am writing a file\n        To read it back\n'